# Google Spreadsheet Script - does not record user email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

In my Google Spreadsheet I log last modification of cell in each row.

When I edit cells from my account it records my user (as email), when somebody makes a edit from other account it shows empty user name or `?`.

Here goes Google script.

```
function onEdit(e) {
...
  ss.getRange(r.getRow(), ss.getLastColumn()).setValue(e.user.getEmail() + " " + date + " \"" + column_name + "\"");
...
}
```

Result when I edit:

```
*******@gmail.com 11:09 [08-11-2012] "SOME VALUE"
```

Result when somebody else edits:

```
? 09:54 [08-11-2012] "SOME VALUE"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation doesn't appear to address this directly.  In theory, that event should be returning the [owner of the spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events) (which may not be what you want anyway, if you are trying to create an audit trail).

It certainly seems like the acting of a deliberate security policy, based on precedent set in the description of `getActiveUser` [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_session).  I suppose you could try accessing the user in the various ways provided by `Session`, and see if you have better luck.